# BIOS can not find hard disk in boot priorities

Tags: linux, hard-drive, boot, bios, grub

I was installing Linux Kali os 2.0 but have got an error while installing grub, so I was unable to start installed kali os and also second OS, Windows 8.1.

Only what was possible was to start live USB from USB I installed that Linux.

BIOS can't find hard disk in boot priorities, so I can use computer only from live USB. I fixed that with installation of grub by reinstalling Linux, it installed also grub but this time successfully.

Computer restarted, but BIOS still can not find hard disk and I can still use only live USB.

In live USB I can explore hard disk as normal disk, but BIOS can not find any partition of that disk.

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 0):

Try reinstalling grub on your hard disk MBR. Boot your Kali livecd once more and, from a command line, assuming a single disk drive, type

`sudo grub-install /dev/sda` (this installs it in the mbr),

and then type `sudo update-grub` (this updates the grub menu)

Comment: Installing for i386-pc platform.
grub-install: warning: this GPT partition label contains no BIOS Boot Partition; embedding won't be possible.
grub-install: warning: Embedding is not possible.  GRUB can only be installed in this setup by using blocklists.  However, blocklists are UNRELIABLE and their use is discouraged..
grub-install: error: will not proceed with blocklists.      // Have no idea what to do. creat another paritiotion and instal it there? for example sdaX x=number of sda